# Im using a BNO055 In the IMU operation mode, but i can only get it to display 0's

Tags: python, imu, i2c

Ive read the data sheet but cant find much info there, but when I try to get IMU to give me euler data (yaw,pitch,roll).
It gives me not accurate numbers for euler data and i cant use the adafruit bno055 library since it keeps giving me errors.

```
#%%
import smbus2

# BNO055 sensor I2C address
bno055_address = 0x28  


i2c_bus = 1  

# I2C bus instance
bus = smbus2.SMBus(i2c_bus)

# Set the BNO055 to IMU mode by writing to the Operation Mode register (0x3D)
bus.write_byte_data(bno055_address, 0x3D, 0x08)

try:
    # Read pitch, yaw, and roll data
    pitch = bus.read_byte_data(bno055_address, 0x1E)  # EUL_Pitch LSB
    yaw = bus.read_byte_data(bno055_address, 0x1C)    # EUL_Heading LSB
    roll = bus.read_byte_data(bno055_address, 0x1A)   # EUL_Roll LSB

    # Calculate the actual angles using the formula Data LSB  / 16
    pitch_deg = pitch  / 16.0
    yaw_deg = yaw  / 16.0
    roll_deg = roll / 16.0

    print("Pitch:", pitch_deg)
    print("Yaw:", yaw_deg)
    print("Roll:", roll_deg)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

bus.close()
```

Comment: Do you have 2 pullup resistors on your circuit?
You can check it by using a ohm-meter between the +V and the SDA wire. Then repeat the same for the SCL wire. Usually you should something not less then 150 Ohm